# How to change default EventId for UnhandledExceptionin in dotnet Core?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, nlog, unhandled-exception

I use NLog for my application logging, every things goes right except UnhandledException.
I use EventId as 1 for my other logs, for example for viewing a list. but when my application raises an unhandled exception, The produced log uses EventId 1 to show Unhandled Exception.

for better demonstration, I paste my codes here

**Here is NLOG Config at nlog.config file**

```
<target name="Initial" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\HyperNovaLogs\${shortdate}\${level}\AppLogs-${level}_${shortdate}.log"
        keepFileOpen="true"
        encoding="utf-8"
        archiveAboveSize ="5000000"
        maxArchiveFiles="100"
        layout="${newline}•LogStart${newline}
                ${newline} ▸Level :${uppercase:${level}}◾
                ${newline} ▸Date :${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}◾
                ${newline} ▸Time :${time:format=HH:mm:ss.mm}◾
                ${newline} ▸IP :${aspnet-request-ip}◾
                ${newline} ▸RequestMethod :${aspnet-request-method}◾
                ${newline} ▸RequestUrl :${aspnet-request-url}◾
                ${newline} ▸ControllerName :${aspnet-mvc-controller}◾
                ${newline} ▸ActionName :${aspnet-mvc-action}◾
                ${newline} ▸RequestUserAgent :${aspnet-request-useragent}◾
                ${newline} ▸ResponseStatusCode :${aspnet-response-statuscode}◾
                ${newline} ▸UserAuthType :${aspnet-user-authtype}◾
                ${newline} ▸UserIdentity :${aspnet-user-identity}◾
                ${newline} ▸IsUserAuth :${aspnet-user-isauthenticated}◾
                ${newline} ▸RequestCookies :${aspnet-request-cookie}◾
                ${newline} ▸RequestHeaders :${aspnet-request-headers}◾
                ${newline} ▸MethodLocation :${callsite}◾
                ${newline} ▸OccuresLocation :${logger}◾
                ${newline} ▸EventId :${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}◾
                ${newline} ▸EventName :${event-properties:item=EventId_Name}◾
                ${newline} ▸Message :${message}◾
                ${newline} ▸Exceptions :${exception:format=tostring}◾${newline}
                ${newline}•LogEnd${newline}"/>
```

**Here is Program.cs Config**

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging((hostingcontext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingcontext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
            logging.AddNLog();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
        })
        .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
}
```

**Here is the produced log example**

```
 •LogStart

 ▸Level :ERROR◾                     
 ▸Date :2020-04-28◾                     
 ▸Time :15:28:26.9711◾                     
 ▸IP :127.0.0.1◾                     
 ▸RequestMethod :GET◾                     
 ▸RequestUrl :http://localhost/AppUsers/ListAll◾                     
 ▸ControllerName :AppUsers◾                     
 ▸ActionName :ListAll◾                     
 ▸RequestUserAgent :Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0◾                     
 ▸ResponseStatusCode :200◾                     
 ▸UserAuthType :Identity.Application◾                     
 ▸UserIdentity :1729476546◾                     
 ▸IsUserAuth :1◾                     
 ▸RequestCookies :AAD_HyperNovaShield=CfDJ8G0KT3XSLH1GgpZLGciXkemkUFxYHlp8ER0fR9MAswI9GyRbRKRFFjkbxn0ctAobsHZgvvrEMaRqns3OBIXL9atQvz-rW2c4Ac0YMoWW0wgN6wC-pEvQuW0uWMO_z-CpiSGmK8zBtDWFkWcu6yXrjUo,AAD_HyperNovaAppAuth=CfDJ8G0KT3XSLH1GgpZLGciXkem-ToC83OMQXH59CZrCIRqTzERMAy26h7oKEX0FwqrzF0rjnAHqM3Mv--9Gjz9mxBrlDI15o9ZYxvtN2lMNPftML7c1CN93L0f3WNHCeQc0P5pym4zC9ArV0dMfNONsX4pE_1yIYe-ecroBAS-653nZBuEyRudH6RqdjOoR-7yhjJbCNvo63y7MZt7Uxn63O6Ifk8qC_ti4mE9EkiTHwJ8Hn5_uvCoJs71kT6o2fXPQ62heyPbouUCjaLuDl3XG-oG8sItDAoNvilZUSsiV-P0w52-NfAr4FAgLKSRQAJENI-7MYTXNKIdba3pz-_8rMJem4PQDysEQOqNJWJI2mHsfAHsp9CCrHWmANxWYNI-LnoaoOzJeM1EBBgjItJ_nSQHvbPhh7rDsdw87yk-zak2Yd6FwEozT406trAsfeM5AkX8X7TfZyMyls-NJfoePzvb6t_cfrJUVTH6SwGk2FXMwpb7BRio6M7vgCdjPcK2F0U3XRCMxXi-C9nnS4dZ2ARMPg09A5GOlLixLTSHJyAp_9li6d6eBD4Hg_lm_D82JrOcnLcDKYdlbdSbS8cmaha8◾                     
 ▸RequestHeaders :Connection=keep-alive,Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8,Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate,Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5,Cookie=AAD_HyperNovaShield=CfDJ8G0KT3XSLH1GgpZLGciXkemkUFxYHlp8ER0fR9MAswI9GyRbRKRFFjkbxn0ctAobsHZgvvrEMaRqns3OBIXL9atQvz-rW2c4Ac0YMoWW0wgN6wC-pEvQuW0uWMO_z-CpiSGmK8zBtDWFkWcu6yXrjUo; AAD_HyperNovaAppAuth=CfDJ8G0KT3XSLH1GgpZLGciXkem-ToC83OMQXH59CZrCIRqTzERMAy26h7oKEX0FwqrzF0rjnAHqM3Mv--9Gjz9mxBrlDI15o9ZYxvtN2lMNPftML7c1CN93L0f3WNHCeQc0P5pym4zC9ArV0dMfNONsX4pE_1yIYe-ecroBAS-653nZBuEyRudH6RqdjOoR-7yhjJbCNvo63y7MZt7Uxn63O6Ifk8qC_ti4mE9EkiTHwJ8Hn5_uvCoJs71kT6o2fXPQ62heyPbouUCjaLuDl3XG-oG8sItDAoNvilZUSsiV-P0w52-NfAr4FAgLKSRQAJENI-7MYTXNKIdba3pz-_8rMJem4PQDysEQOqNJWJI2mHsfAHsp9CCrHWmANxWYNI-LnoaoOzJeM1EBBgjItJ_nSQHvbPhh7rDsdw87yk-zak2Yd6FwEozT406trAsfeM5AkX8X7TfZyMyls-NJfoePzvb6t_cfrJUVTH6SwGk2FXMwpb7BRio6M7vgCdjPcK2F0U3XRCMxXi-C9nnS4dZ2ARMPg09A5GOlLixLTSHJyAp_9li6d6eBD4Hg_lm_D82JrOcnLcDKYdlbdSbS8cmaha8,Host=localhost:8080,User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0,Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1◾                     
 ▸MethodLocation :Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsLoggerExtensions.UnhandledException◾                     
 ▸OccuresLocation :Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware◾                     
 ▸EventId :1◾                     
 ▸EventName :UnhandledException◾                     
 ▸Message :An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.◾                     
 ▸Exceptions :System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot return null from an action method with a return type of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.EnsureActionResultNotNull(ObjectMethodExecutor executor, IActionResult actionResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)◾

•LogEnd
```

What I want is changing this default EventId as 1 for UnhandledException.
Actually, the question is: How can I change default EventIds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe replace this:

```
${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}
```

With this:

```
${when:when='${event-properties:item=EventId_Name}'=='UnhandledException':inner=42:else=${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}}
```

It will now print EventId=42 for `UnhandledException`. See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, this answer helps alot but is there still another way to change it from the base for all other raised unhandled exceptions?

Let me ask this in other hand. How to retrieve all current Event_Id & Event_Names

Comment: @MazMazDevelopers Sounds like a different question and unrelated to NLog, but general for AspNetCore-applications. The `EventId_Id` and `EventId_Name` gets their value from the EventId-parameter provided when logging with MEL-ILogger. NLog does not control the EventId-input provided. You can try and scan the AspNetCore-framework code-base at github for all EventId-types currently being used.